# How can I resign from one text field to the next while hiding the previous text field?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I currently have four text fields. At the beginning, only one text field shows. After the user enters text to the first text field and taps a button a new text field is presented and the previous one is hidden with the text field hidden property. My current code only shows the first text field, hides it and shows a new one, and stays in the second text field. There are still two more text fields that need to have the same functionality.

[image: First Text Field IMAGE]

[image: Second Text Field IMAGE]

[image: Stuck in Second Text Field IMAGE]

Can you explain why my current code is not working?

Thank you

This is my current code

```
if nameTextField.text != nil {
      nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
      emailTextField.isHidden = false
      nameTextField.isHidden = true
      emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if emailTextField.text != nil {
      emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
      emailTextField.isHidden = true
      firstPasswordTextField.isHidden = false
      firstPasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if firstPasswordTextField.text != nil {
      firstPasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
      firstPasswordTextField.isHidden = true
      phoneNumberTextField.isHidden = false
      phoneNumberTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if phoneNumberTextField.text != nil {
      phoneNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: Don't check your textfield text nill condition check textfield object and outlet of that textfield and then in endediting put your login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Mathew the condition what you have written is incorrect . Lets say user first enter in nameTextField and then you are checking emailTextField not equal to nil.. Sone ones user enter in both the textfield , it is always going to satisfy the first condition only.. Just put a brteakpoint and check your logic.